# JQuery DataTables - dynamically change page numbering

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I want to be able change the page numbers for JQuery datatables. The page numbers start from 1 by default and depending upon the number of items you have configured to display per page, you'll get a certain page numbers displayed at the bottom of your table. I have a set number of records being fetched from the server each time and therefore want to change the page numbers accordingly.

For example

- Fetch 1: First Previous 1 2 3 4 5  Next Last
- Fetch 2: First Previous 6 7 8 9 10 Next Last

Are there any JQuery Datatables API method available to change the page number labels?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has [pagingType](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) options that can have one of the values below:

> `simple` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
>
> `simple_numbers` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
>
> `full` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons
>
> `full_numbers` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers

Default value for `pagingType` option is `simple_numbers`.

In addition, there are [pagination plug-ins](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/) that offer alternative appearance of the pagination control.

Comment: Hi, I cant find a way to modify button labels. For example, by default all the buttons are labelled 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on...How can I  modify the labels to One, Two, Three, Four? Also, what if I wanted the labels to start from 10 instead of 1 like 10, 11, 12, 13 etc. Appreciate any clues you can provide!

Comment: @AbhiRampal, it is only possibly if you write a pagination plug-in. There are some pagination plug-ins already available [on DataTables site](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/). If you figure out, how they work, you can write yours. Otherwise it's not possible using DataTables API only.